# Syntax highlighting for autotools (autoconf/automake/m4)

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I'm writing beamer slides showcasing how to use the [autotools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Autotools) and would like to highlight my configuration examples. [listings](https://ctan.org/pkg/listings) and [minted](https://ctan.org/pkg/minted) ([pygments](https://pygments.org/)) don't seem to support any of the possible names for this language (I searched for autotools, automake, autoconf and m4). Is there a latex package out there than can highlight this or must I define a custom lexer for listings/pygments?

Comment: There are pygments-lexer for m4, e.g., https://github.com/FabriceSalvaire/pygments-lexer . I've never had any experience with it, so I'm not sure if it's the right thing for you. But I would like to suggest that you go and try it out.

Comment: Thanks @cabohah, that would at least ease the "define a custom lexer" solution, though for minted I'll have to look up to include it in the build process.